# UpdateView will correctly show model data but wont actually save the update

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I am trying to get my UpdateView to load the current data into the form -> allow the user to make changes-> update the object and persist the changes to the database. So far I have this code:

```
class SurveyInitUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = SurveyInit
    template_name = 'Model/surveyInit.html'
    form_class = SurveyInitForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Model:myModel-home')

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.object = SurveyInit.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object, form=form)
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
```

So far it will correctly load the user's data and allow them to enter changes in the form but when the user submits it will not change the object or the database information! Thank you for any help!

Per request here is my template:

```
{% block body %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h3>Header</h3>
                    {% if error_message %}
                        <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
                    {% endif %}
                    <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% include 'Model/form-template.html' %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>{% endblock %}
```

The Model/form-template.html is a simple for loop that iterates through the Form Fields.

I tried adding this post method but it only creates a new entity and does not update the current one.

```
    def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        sub = form.save(commit=False)
        sub.user = request.user
        sub.save()
    return redirect('Model:myModel-home')
```

Update: I don't think overriding the post method is needed.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your template

Comment: So judging from your comment, I will need to change the method to post with an if statement. This raises the question of how to send the dictionary with the template. Thank you for you input @Jaberwocky

Comment: Yes, your method should be "post".  You shouldn't need to do much if you're using the `UpdateView` class.  That's the beauty of the in-built views of Django.  It handles the data for you.  Of course it's not so great for complex forms, but either way...

Comment: Except I am wrong because there is not Put method hahaha

Comment: No, there isn't.  Although if you were using DRF there could be :)  Either way, it's always best to refer to the django repo for good detailed information of pretty much anything.  https://github.com/django/django/blob/d79cf1e9e2887aa12567c8f27e384195253cb847/django/views/generic/edit.py

Comment: I did look at this and attempted to override the POST method but when I do it creates a new entity instead of updating the current one.

Comment: Update your code

Comment: To what @Jaberwocky?

Comment: Your views.py :)

Comment: I posted the post method I tried @Jaberwocky

Comment: Why do you need to override the get or post method?  It seems to me you're just doing that to be able to assign a user to the data you're submitting?

Comment: I think you need to post your forms.py and models.py so I can get a clearer picture.

Comment: @jaberwocky my forms and models are very basic.  Just some char fields in the model and labels  in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was returning the User object instead of the SurveyInit object (The model for the form)